# Banded matrix with random entries

Tags: matrices, random-numbers

What is the optimal way to get [banded matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix) with random entries in LaTeX? By random, I mean the following: It should give me different entries after every compilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use any random number generator function. Here is an example of the one using the one built in `pgf`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf}


\newcommand{\Rand}{\pgfmathparse{random(100)}\pgfmathresult}%

\newcommand{\NewMatrix}{%
\begin{bmatrix}
  \Rand & 0     & 0       \\
  0     & \Rand &  0      \\
  0     & 0     & \Rand 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
}%

\begin{document}
$\NewMatrix$, $\NewMatrix$, $\NewMatrix$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Essentially I was looking for a good random number generator.

Comment: @Marvis: OK, If I get done with the flexible random banded matrix generator, I'll post it separately.

Comment: I managed to write a banded matrix generator using your code. The only thing is every time I compile, I get the same set of matrices. Is it possible to get a different one each time?

Comment: @Marvis: I think you just need to set the seed to be the current second -- you should get different results each minute (I think) by default.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Every minute it gives a different number now.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the cue from Peter, here is the code I wrote to generate a random matrix and a random banded matrix.

`$$\NewMatrix{m}{n}$$` produces a matrix of size `m` by `n`.

`$$\BandMatrix{m}{n}{b}$$`produces a matrix of size `m` by `n` with bandwidth b.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\Rand}{\pgfmathparse{random(10)}\pgfmathresult}%

\newcounter{row_number}
\newcounter{col_number}
\newcounter{band}

\newcommand{\NewMatrix}[2]{%
\begin{bmatrix}
  \forloop{row_number}{1}{\value{row_number} < #1}{%%
    \forloop{col_number}{1}{\value{col_number} < #2}{%%%
        \Rand & 
    }%%%
    \Rand
    \\
  }%%
  \forloop{col_number}{1}{\value{col_number} < #2}{%%%%
        \Rand & 
    }%%%%
    \Rand
\end{bmatrix}
}%

\newcommand{\BandMatrix}[3]{%
\begin{bmatrix}
  \forloop{row_number}{1}{\value{row_number} < #1}{%%
    \forloop{col_number}{1}{\value{col_number} < #2}{%%%
        \ifthenelse{\value{col_number} < \numexpr\value{row_number} + #3 + 1 \and \value{col_number} > \numexpr\value{row_number} - #3 - 1}{\Rand &}{0 &}
    }%%%
    \ifthenelse{\value{col_number} < \numexpr\value{row_number} + #3 + 1 \and \value{col_number} > \numexpr\value{row_number} - #3 - 1}{\Rand \\}{0 \\}
  }%%
  \forloop{col_number}{1}{\value{col_number} < #2}{%%%%
        \ifthenelse{\value{col_number} < \numexpr\value{row_number} + #3 + 1 \and \value{col_number} > \numexpr\value{row_number} - #3 - 1}{\Rand &}{0 &}
    }%%%%
    \ifthenelse{\value{col_number} < \numexpr\value{row_number} + #3 + 1 \and \value{col_number} > \numexpr\value{row_number} - #3 - 1}{\Rand}{0}
\end{bmatrix}
}%

\begin{document}
$$\NewMatrix{11}{4}$$
$$\BandMatrix{10}{8}{3}$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\[...\]` for display math instead of `$$`. See: [Why is \\[ … \\] preferable to $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: Also, wonder if your condition of where the band is is off by 1. You specify `8` and `3` in `\BandMatrix`, but the first `4` rows are non-zero, and the first 6 columns are zero.  I haven't dealt with banded-matrices before so perhaps I am misunderstood the specification.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this so as to allow for more rows/columns? Looks like they are capped at 11.